# Trying to make inside background turn black, while outside plays a gif

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEcCI.jpg)

I'm trying to create a background inside css that enables me to have the inside of the border be black, and the outside to be running a gif. Is there a way for me to do this? Following code for the body is this.

```
body{
    max-width: 650px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: silver;
    background-image: url("images/Matrix_Code.gif");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Don't try to do all your styling on a single element.  Put the matrix background gif on the `body` like you have it, remove all the other `body` styling and move it to a different DOM element with `background-color: #000`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a div inside body.
This is stylesheet

```
<style>
        body {
            padding:0;
            background-image: url("matrix.gif");
            background-size: cover;
        }

        div.inside {
            max-width: 650px;
            padding: 15px;
            margin: 15px auto;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: silver;
            background-color:black;
            color:#fff;
        }
    </style>
```

This is html code for body

```
body>
    <div class="inside">
        put your content here
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The only issue is i have a div created for tabs, and it seems to conflict with it in css. Would there be another way? Or do divs usually not supposed to conflict?

Comment: @ZaccharySumrall I am not able to understand your requirement exactly. you can have multiple divs that can be nested too.

Comment: Figured it out. Float was causing the issue, so I removed it. Thank you for the advice :) this idea worked.